# Serialize DIV content

Tags: jquery

I was trying to apply http://jsbin.com/mehupisuhi/1/edit but my code is different, with more divs and classes:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="type_list">
   <div class="clonedOperation" id="typeSequence1">
      <div class="container1">
         <label></label>
         <div class="col1"><span class="heading-reference" name="reference" id="reference">1.</span></div>
         <div class="col2">
            <select style="width: 100px;" id="type_operation_1" name="type_operation_1" class="select_type_operation">
               <option disabled="" selected="" value="">None </option>

            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col3"><select style="width: 100px;" id="select_type_input_1" name="select_type_input_1" class="select_type_input"></select></div>
         <div class="col4"><input style="width: 50px;height:22px;" name="type_operation_rate_1" id="type_operation_rate_1" class="type_operation_rate" kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"></div>
         <div class="col5"><select style="width: 70px;" id="select_type_unit_1" name="select_type_unit_1" class="type_operation_unit"></select></div>
         <div class="col6"><button class="btn btn-info edit_type_button" type="button" id="edit_type_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
         <div class="col7"><button class="btn btn-danger remove_type_button" type="button" id="remove_type_1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clonedOperation" id="typeSequence2" style="display: block;">
      <div class="container1">
         <label></label>
         <div class="col1"><span class="heading-reference" name="ID2_reference" id="ID2_reference">2.</span></div>
         <div class="col2">
            <select style="width: 100px;" id="type_operation_2" name="type_operation_2" class="select_type_operation">
               <option disabled="" selected="" value="">None </option>

            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col3"><select style="width: 100px;" id="select_type_input_2" name="select_type_input_2" class="select_type_input"></select></div>
         <div class="col4"><input style="width: 50px;height:22px;" name="type_operation_rate_2" id="type_operation_rate_2" class="type_operation_rate" kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"></div>
         <div class="col5"><select style="width: 70px;" id="select_type_unit_2" name="select_type_unit_2" class="type_operation_unit"></select></div>
         <div class="col6"><button class="btn btn-info edit_type_button" type="button" id="edit_type_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
         <div class="col7"><button class="btn btn-danger remove_type_button" type="button" id="remove_type_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clonedOperation" id="typeSequence3" style="display: block;">
      <div class="container1">
         <label></label>
         <div class="col1"><span class="heading-reference" name="ID3_reference" id="ID3_reference">3.</span></div>
         <div class="col2">
            <select style="width: 100px;" id="type_operation_3" name="type_operation_3" class="select_type_operation">
               <option disabled="" selected="" value="">None </option>

            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col3"><select style="width: 100px;" id="select_type_input_3" name="select_type_input_3" class="select_type_input"></select></div>
         <div class="col4"><input style="width: 50px;height:22px;" name="type_operation_rate_3" id="type_operation_rate_3" class="type_operation_rate" kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"></div>
         <div class="col5"><select style="width: 70px;" id="select_type_unit_3" name="select_type_unit_3" class="type_operation_unit"></select></div>
         <div class="col6"><button class="btn btn-info edit_type_button" type="button" id="edit_type_3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
         <div class="col7"><button class="btn btn-danger remove_type_button" type="button" id="remove_type_3"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clonedOperation" id="typeSequence4" style="display: block; opacity: 0.994636;">
      <div class="container1">
         <label></label>
         <div class="col1"><span class="heading-reference" name="ID4_reference" id="ID4_reference">4.</span></div>
         <div class="col2">
            <select style="width: 100px;" id="type_operation_4" name="type_operation_4" class="select_type_operation">
               <option disabled="" selected="" value="">None </option>

            </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col3"><select style="width: 100px;" id="select_type_input_4" name="select_type_input_4" class="select_type_input"></select></div>
         <div class="col4"><input style="width: 50px;height:22px;" name="type_operation_rate_4" id="type_operation_rate_4" class="type_operation_rate" kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"></div>
         <div class="col5"><select style="width: 70px;" id="select_type_unit_4" name="select_type_unit_4" class="type_operation_unit"></select></div>
         <div class="col6"><button class="btn btn-info edit_type_button" type="button" id="edit_type_4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></div>
         <div class="col7"><button class="btn btn-danger remove_type_button" type="button" id="remove_type_4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using:

```
$(function() {
    //define the array
    var operator = [];
    //start looping
    $('#type_list .clonedOperation').each(function(i , e) {
        //automatically add to each pair of tune elements an equal class name
        $(this).children().attr('class','clonedOperation_'+i);
        //create and convert the array to JSON
        operator.push( $.toJSON( $('.clonedOperation_'+i).serializeObject() ) );
    });
    //join all tunes into one comma separated sting
    var operatorFinal = operator.join(",");
    alert( operatorFinal );
});
```

But I am confused because the alert is coming empty, I know it is because it's not serializing the clonedOperation.

How can I serialize the fields in a JSON like the example above?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `tune` is in your code, but I suspect it's your actual mistake. But here's some code that will do what I think you want to do:

Here's just a generic function, and below is exactly what you're trying to do. *I think*

```
var jsonAllTheThings = function(class){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(class);
  var packedElements = JSON.stringify(elements);
  return packedElements;
};

//OR more specifically

var doAllTheseSteps = function(){
  var operator = [];

  var parent = document.getElementById('type_list');
  var idsChildren = parent.children();
  for(var i = 0; i < idsChildren.length; i++){
    var child = idsChildren[i];
    child.classList.add("clonedOperation_" + i);
    operator.push(JSON.stringify(child));
  }
  var operatorFinal = operator.join(",");
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But after put your idea I just removed "var parent = document.getElementById('type_list')" for "var parent = $.("#type_list)" but both are giving this answer:  {"sizzle-1432647009751":{"parentNode":["7950 208",48]}},{"jQuery19101185598873828061":551,"sizzle-1432647009751":{"parentNode":["7950 208",54]}},{"sizzle-1432647009751":{"parentNode":["7950 208",60]}}

Comment: And the idea is get my fields in a JSON like this:[{type_operation_1: value, select_type_input_1: value, type_operation_rate_1: value, select_type_unit_1: value, },
{type_operation_2: value, select_type_input_2: value, type_operation_rate_2: value, select_type_unit_2: value, },
{type_operation_3: value, select_type_input_3: value, type_operation_rate_3: value, select_type_unit_3: value, },
{type_operation_4: value, select_type_input_4: value, type_operation_rate_4: value, select_type_unit_4: value, }] - The last number will always increase or decrease because I can insert 15 lines.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

Send from JQUERY using $.post(form);

And with PHP just get all data and serialize in an array and insert into database with a foreach.

Thanks.